# Keras multi input model loss plummets, doesn't train

Tags: python, keras

While using keras's multi-input model, the model just doesn't train at all. The accuracy skyrockets to near 100% and the loss plummets, so I think there's something wrong with the data generation.

I'm using a multi-input keras model, with two images of the same object, just rotated. The plan is to run each image through it's own CNN, then concatenate the two flattened layers and classify the object.

I prepare the data using the method found (here)[https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8130]. The images are in separate directories but with the same seeding, they get loaded correctly. The labels are also correct, I've checked by looking at the filenames and the directories that the ImageDataGenerator generates.

The model is simple enough, I don't think it's causing the problem

```
def multiInput_model():
    #create model - custom

    input_1 = Input(shape=(img_width,img_height,1))
    input_2 = Input(shape=(img_width,img_height,1))   

    output_1 = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu')(input_1)
    output_1 = BatchNormalization()(output_1)
    output_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(output_1)
    output_1 = Dropout(0.4)(output_1)
    output_1 = Flatten()(output_1)

    output_2 = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu')(input_2)
    output_2 = BatchNormalization()(output_2)
    output_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(output_2)
    output_2 = Dropout(0.4)(output_2)
    output_2 = Flatten()(output_2)

    inputs = [input_1,input_2]
    outputs = [output_1,output_2]
    combine = concatenate(outputs)

    output = Dense(32,activation='relu')(combine)
    output = Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax')(output)


    model = Model(inputs,[output])


    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 optimizer='RMSprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

The image generators are as follows

```
def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, dir2, batch_size, img_width,img_height,subset):
    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                                      color_mode='grayscale',
                                      target_size= 
                                      (img_width,img_height),
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      class_mode='categorical',
                                      shuffle=False,
                                      subset=subset,
                                      seed=1)
                                      #Same seed for consistency.

    genX2 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                                      color_mode='grayscale',
                                      target_size= 
                                      (img_width,img_height),
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      class_mode='categorical',
                                      shuffle=False,
                                      subset=subset,
                                      seed=1)
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        yield [X1i[0],X2i[0]],X1i[1]    #Yields both images and their mutual label



train_generator = 
generate_generator_multiple(generator=train_datagen,
                                          dir1=train_data_dirA,
                                          dir2=train_data_dirB,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          img_width=img_width,
                                          img_height=img_height,
                                          subset='training')

validation_generator =  
generate_generator_multiple(generator=train_datagen,
                                               dir1=train_data_dirA,
                                               dir2=train_data_dirB,
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               img_width=img_width,
                                               img_height=img_height,
                                               subset='validation')
```

The output is always like this

```
20/20 [==============================] - 4s 183ms/step - loss: 0.1342 - acc: 0.9500 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/20
20/20 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 8.0590 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/20
20/20 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/20
20/20 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

**EDIT**: Ok the algorithm is training somewhat now. The accuracy seems to be improving but the validation accuracy is stuck at 0.111 (which is 1/9, meaning the network is just guessing at the label of the image). However, the training accuracy does improve so at least it's overfitting (for now).

**EDIT2**: I've manually edited the directories such that I am no longer using subset. The directories are split as follows

```
-dir1 -> train -> class1 -> img...
               -> class2 -> img...
                ....
               -> class9 -> img...
      -> validate -> class1 -> img...
                  -> class2 -> img...
                  ....
                  -> class9 -> img...

-dir2 -> train -> class1 -> img...
               -> class2 -> img...
                ....
               -> class9 -> img...
      -> validate -> class1 -> img...
                  -> class2 -> img...
                  ....
                  -> class9 -> img...
```

The more interesting point now is that the validation loss increases while the training loss decreases. From running 4 epochs, these are the results

```
126/126 [==============================] - 92s 730ms/step - loss: 
1.7158 - acc: 0.6583 - val_loss: 4.4013 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 2/20
126/126 [==============================] - 88s 698ms/step - loss: 
1.2179 - acc: 0.7859 - val_loss: 5.5854 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 3/20
126/126 [==============================] - 88s 700ms/step - loss: 
0.9849 - acc: 0.8308 - val_loss: 6.2045 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 4/20
126/126 [==============================] - 89s 705ms/step - loss: 
0.9357 - acc: 0.8513 - val_loss: 6.9400 - val_acc: 0.1111
```

**Update**
Image pairs and labels of images have been checked. All labels for images are correct. All images are paired correctly.

Comment: Is it possible you are overfitting? How many images do you have in your training set?

Comment: @Roni 700x2 images per category for training and 300x2 image per category for validation. Also see edit

Comment: hard to know without seeing the structure of your training data directories but i suspect the problem is coming from a problem with what you are pulling from them. having 1/9 val accuracy could likely be a symptom of **labels not matching samples**. is the `subset` argument working?

Comment: @lunguini Yes that's what I thought initially, so I've manually edited the directories. I'll edit the post. Furthermore, is there a manual way to check the labels and sample matching?

Comment: try getting random samples of the images and their label. Plot them `plt.imshow(x)` and see if the labels are correct, maybe?

Comment: @zwang what is the image size? I suspect your dense layer has too many parameters and that's why it overfits.
 model.summary() may help with that.

Comment: @Roni Yes I think you may be right. I'm currently running each stream of data through my single image model, and it's not training properly either. I think the model might indeed be underfitting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really an answer but my question has too many updates:

First and foremost, I've found that by setting shuffle=False it wasn't training. By changing shuffle=true, some results were actually coming to light!

Secondly, the model wasn't deep enough. Adding another convolutional layer (or two) helped significantly.

As to why setting shuffle=True helped. I think it's because if all the data goes through the network in the same fashion, the same way everytime, it's bound to not train well as it doesn't bring much variance to the model. By setting shuffle=True, and the same seed for both cases, this meant that the shuffle amount would be the same (hence the images would still be paired correctly) but the order of which they go through the network is different.

If anyone can add additional information, please do.

Answer (score 0):

low training loss and high val loss usually point to overfit.

in this case it could be that the output from the first conv layer is too large to be fed into a dense layer, which results in a huge weights matrix inside the dense layer that overfits the data.

perhaps stacking more `Conv2d` + `MaxPooling2d` layers will reduce the input size to the dense layer and it will result in a decrease of the total amount of parameters in the neural net, helping you to deal with the overfit.